# What is "|" operator?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, eip, erc

I have been going through the ERC998 contract and came across this:

```
return (ERC998_MAGIC_VALUE << 224) | bytes32(rootOwnerAddress)
```

What is this "|" operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Bitwise Operator, more you can read about it here [LINK](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html).